# How do I answer a question that no-one has asked... but is related to questions that are being asked?

Tags: discussion

Where can I post 'helpful ideas' that are not being asked directly, but are being asked indirectly?

I see some of the vigilant members being very vigilant with innocuous comments or requests for more information or generally helpful but not specific enough comments which get pinged for being 'off topic'.

As a classroom teacher of some 25 years I do notice when someone needs help but may not be articulate enough or skilled enough to know exactly what to ask or how to ask it. I find these sites unnecessarily exacting and frustrating and I'm sure others do, too.

Comment: Thank you for the direction. I suppose one must know exactly what it is one wants to offer, and it never having been asked that way before, before one can genuinely post it and not have some zealots pounce. 

It is very intimidating that some folk cannot extend a little grace to those of us who genuinely want to learn and help without being subject to officious behaviour. 

Sure, there are rules - not obvious to beginners - and sure, there are protocols and accepted ways of doing things - not obvious until the thought police do their thing - but why so aggressive? 

It is very off-putting.